# Android project type not supporting in visual studio

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2010, xamarin

i installed Xamarin Enterprise edition on my computer 9 days ago. It worked fine and i have crated some projects and tested it on Emulators. But after some times- today when i come back to work, restarted computer and tried to open Android project On visual studio. It says: **The project type is not supported by this installation.** What is going on. What i can do?

I use Visual Studio 2010.

I tried to open Tools-> Options-> Xamarin-> Android Settings
But it shows: **An error occurred loading this property page**

Answer (score 1):

First uninstall the `Xamarin.Android` plugin from the `Control Panel`. Then, try to completely remove the `extensions` from the `control panel`.

Remove `any` residual files from: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Extensions %PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin`

Then, re-install `Xamarin.Android` from the following `msi` file: 
[Xamarin.Android on Windows](http://download.xamarin.com/MonoforAndroid/Windows/mono-android-4.8.03015.msi)

Comment: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8993/the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installation i have done it before but did not removed extendions from  %PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin. But now it works.

Comment: But where is my IOS? i can not see it. May be it is removed ?